# Clear(remove) combobox items throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I have combobox which is correctly populated with some field ID when button is clicked.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    results.Items.Add(ID);          
}
```

Now I want when I change some value to delete previous value (or values in case I have multiple values in combobox) but I am always getting exception (if some value is already selected in Combo Box)
I tried to add in that method on the top this:

```
results.Items.Clear();
```

and I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Items.Count; i++)
{
    results.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
}
```

But always getting exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>          at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
>   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
>   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Add[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection'1 collection, Object value)
>   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection'1.AddImpl(Object value)
>   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.AddImpl(Object value)
>   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.AddInternal(Object value)
>   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection'1.Add(T value)
>   at SXPCreateIncident3.SilverlightControl1.results_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
>   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArg

If I don't have this part with Clear (Remove) then combobox has more elements on every button Click but I need to clear previous content when button is clicked.

Comment: Note: You shouldn't modify the iterator counter inside a for loop (unless you do know what you're doing)...

Comment: Hi OK but why Clear method doe snot work if I already have selected some item in Combobox?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try unselecting all items before deleting:

```
results.SelectedIndex = -1;
results.Items.Clear();
```

And in case Clear would still cause some trouble, shouldn't your second method be:

```
for (int i = results.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    results.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how `result.Items` is bound to you `Combobox` but you might try to replace the unwanted item with a new one:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // itemToRemove should already be set    
    var index = result.Items.IndexOf(itemToRemove);     
    results.Items[index ] = ID;          
}
```

To remove multiple items, do not use an iterator. Removing things from a collection while using an iterator messes the iterator up. You could however do this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        // itemsToRemove should be populated with the IDs you want to remove.
        if(itemsToRemove.Contains(result.Items[i])
        {
            result.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    result.Items.Add(ID);
}
```

This loop won't get messed up because every time the expression `i < result.Items.Count` is evaluated and `Count` be one less then the previous `Count` when an ID has been removed.

**EDIT** 
To clear the combobox and populate it with new items you'll have to provide a new `ItemsSource` for the combobox:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    results.ItemsSource = null;
    results.ItemsSource = new List<SomeType>(); // replace SomeType with the type of ID.
    results.Items.Add(ID);          
}
```

Comment: Hi Venerik thanks but what is itemsToRemove??? I want to remove all. How should I then set this itemsToRemove?

Comment: You wrote "Now I want when I change some value to delete previous value (or values in case I have multiple values in combobox)". So I assumed you somehow keep track of the values you want to remove. That are the values you should put in the `itemsToRemove`.

Comment: Hi venerik I want to remove all values in combox in case I have selected some value in combobox because I want on button click to populate combobox once again from scratch. Is the itemsToRemove some kind of ListBox that I should populate? Or can you please assist me how to populate it before I remove all from combobox?

Comment: Hi unforunately again the same issue: Value does not fall within the expected range. First value is populated correctly but immediately if I select it and click again the button it throws error. ID is value which I retrieve as a string in field ID.   results.ItemsSource = null;
            results.ItemsSource = new List<string>();
            results.Items.Add(ticketID);